# TimeSpan property in Azure Table Storage

Tags: .net, azure, azure-table-storage

I have an entity with a `TimeSpan` property I want to save in Azure Table Storage. When I attempt to save the entity I get the error:

> Can't cast to unsupported type 'TimeSpan'

Is there some way to do an automatic conversion or some other way to support `TimeSpan`?

Answer (score 4):

I store the TimeSpan as ticks in an int or bigint field and convert that. You could also store it as a varchar. I prefer ticks because you can do math on it in the database if you need to and it makes range comparisons easier. If you're using Entity Framework, you can declare an unmapped property that gets and sets a TimeSpan from your database-friendly property.

Have a look at [Entities in Azure Tables](http://convective.wordpress.com/2009/12/30/entities-in-azure-tables/). Part of it describes how to exclude a property from Azure Table Storage, which should make what I proposed with EF workable for ATS as well.

Comment: I'm using Azure Table Storage (NoSQL storage service), so I don't think I can use EF with that. I've already thought of storing the ticks as a long - that's what I'm doing as a work-around at the moment but wanted to see if there's a better way.

Comment: Have a look at http://convective.wordpress.com/2009/12/30/entities-in-azure-tables/. Part of it describes how to exclude a property from Azure Table Storage, which should make what I proposed with EF workable for ATS as well.

Comment: We use ticks here.  Make sure you standardize any times stored to UTC so that applying the ticks will get you the right offset and time.

Comment: @dunnry UTC doesn't apply to TimeSpan unless you're using it as a hack to store time of day, but it is a good point. DateTimeOffset might be better for that purpose though.

Comment: @JamieSee - I should have expounded on that explanation.  We use ticks to calculate datetimes based on offsets (e.g. someDateTime.AddTicks(-ticks)).  Nothing to do with timezones in our case.  We want to know what 15 mins ago was from some datetime we have stored.  That causes problems when you don't standardize on UTC times that you store as well.  It was more of an aside as I upvoted the answer.  From what I have seen, most people use Timespans eventually to calculate a datetime...

Comment: @dunnry Excellent. Thanks for expanding on your comment. I'm sure people will find it helpful. +1

Comment: @JamieSee - Thanks for the link above, I hadn't noticed the events exposed on the DataServiceContext - that looks like something I might be able to use to do the conversion. I've only just started working with Azure but I've gotta say this stuff is so much easier with Amazon AWS - all you need is an attribute on the property and a custom converter.

Answer (score 1):

In order to store a `TimeSpan` into a CloudTable, I'm using a `long` property that does the translation with the `TimeSpan` property:

```
public class MyEntity : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity
{
    public TimeSpan MyDuration { get; set; }

    // Workaround the fact that TableEntity does not automatically store a `TimeSpan` 
    public long MyDurationTicks
    {
        get { return MyDuration.Ticks; }
        set { MyDuration = TimeSpan.FromTicks(value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`TimeSpan` type and even nullable `TimeSpan?` type is supported by Azure Storage SDK > v8.0.0.

Flatten your entity using the static helper method `TableEntity.Flatten` method and write to table storage:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableentity.flatten.aspx

When you read the entity back from table, convert it back to your original entity using `TableEntity.Convertback` method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt775432.aspx

Flatten and Convertback methods support pretty much any type of property except IEnumerable / ICollection type indexed properties.

I have written an TableEntityAdapter class that underneath calls `TableEntity.Flatten` and `ConvertBack` methods and makes it easy for developers to use.

All you need to do is to pass your object to this adapter and that's all.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/TableEntityAdapter/

If you want to learn a bit more how the Flatten and ConvertBack methods  work behind the covers, have a look at the article I wrote.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObjectFlattenerRecomposer/

Answer (score 0):

Because I ran into limitations on the Microsoft client, I have written an alternate Azure table storage client, Lucifure Stash, with many high level abstractions.

Lucifure Stash, supports data columns > 64K, lists, arrays, enumerations, serialization, morphing, public and private properties and fields and more. It is free for personal use and can be downloaded from http://www.lucifure.com  or via NuGet.com (http://nuget.org/packages/LucifureStash).

You can easily use it to morph a TimeSpan into a data type supported by Azure Storage Tables.

Comment: Thanks @Lucifure, I'll take a look at it to see if it fits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

As JamieSee suggested you can store the TimeSpan as ticks in some long int, what you can also do is serialize the object to a Byte Array.

No matter what complex/unsupported class you have you can always serialize it to a Byte Array and upload it, then retrieve, deserialize it and cast it back to whatever type it was. I did this when I needed to upload a List of KeyValuePairs.

You can create automatic conversions in the properties getter and setter.